# Dropdown list selected value from database

Tags: asp.net

I have a table that has a `TypeID` column, amongst others.  This `TypeID` column is a foreign key to another table where type names are populated.

On my aspx page, I have a drop down list whose `selected` field I want to set to whatever `Type Name` that `TypeID` corresponds to.

The confusing part is that I am querying table that just has the `TypeID` so I can't say something like below since I don't have `TypeDesc` in this table.

```
ddl.SelectedItem.Text = dtType.Rows[0]["TypeDesc"].ToString();
```

The way I connect to database to populate the dropdownlist

```
    string sqlType = "SELECT TypeID, TypeDesc FROM .......";

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDB"].ConnectionString))
    {
            SqlCommand comType = new SqlCommand(sqlType, con);
            comType.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
            DataTable dtType = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dtType);
            con.Close();
            ddl.DataTextField = "TypeDesc";
            ddl.DataValueField = "TypeID";
            ddl.DataSource = dtType;
            ddl.DataBind();
    }
```

After above code runs, ddl is successfully populated with items.  This is ddl on the aspx side:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl" runat="server" />
```

After all this is over, I query database again with a different query that selects from a table that only has TypeID (as foreign key to the above table of types).

After i execute this new query, i have a `TypeID`.  I want the ddl to make the selected item the one whose `Value` matches this `TypeID`.

I can get all this to work with

```
ddl.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["TypeID"])-1;
```

but that is assuming that ddl member index is same as TypeIDs. Shouldn't there be an easier way to do this?

Comment: Try ddl.[SelectedValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this code:

```
ddl.SelectedValue = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["TypeID"]);
```

or

```
ddl.SelectedIndex = ddl.Items.IndexOf(ddl.Items.FindByText(dt.Rows[0]["TypeDesc"]));
```

Comment: Thanks! looks like SelectedValue needs a string so i added this `ddl.SelectedValue = (Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[0]["TypeID"])).ToString();`

Comment: u can try this (String)dt.Rows[0]["TypeID"]; or dt.Rows[0]["TypeID"].ToString();

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.  It works for me when i cast it to Int32 then to String.

Comment: @Dust: I tried below code in my system , it is working  ddl.SelectedValue = dt.Rows[0]["TypeID"].ToString();

Comment: yes sir, it works.  I accidentally stored my data as nchar instead of varchar.  nchar apparently reserves the space in the database field which was causing problems.  Thanks for helping!